# plot color scale bar with unequal distance between ticks

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I plot this legend with `ggplot2`?(please figure 2)
Please look at the legend of the interrupt gap between, but they are not equal, I want to let them become equal gap, because my data most distribution between 0 to 3, do that  I want to let the color of the gradient between 0 to 3 to see more, that is to say, legend labels is(0,1,2,4,7,10), and that it is on the legend of equal distribution, as shown in right figure 2 legend

My code(but not plot I want legend):

```
  y = c(seq(0.1,3,0.1),4:10)
  x = seq(0.1, 5, length.out = length(y))
  df = data.frame(x = x, y=y)
  ggplot(df, aes(x,y, color = y)) + geom_point() + 
    scale_color_gradientn(colours = c("blue", "yellow","red"), 
               values = c(0,scales::rescale(c(0,1,2,5,7,10), 
                                      from = range(df$y)),1), 
               breaks = c(0,1,2,4,7,10), limits = c(0,10))
```

Created on 2021-12-29 by the reprex package (v2.0.1)

thank you!

[image: figure 1 my eg]
[image: figure 2]

Comment: I understand what you mean. I have tried to change these parameters, but failed and It's not my goal. I do not your may found my picture, it is very useful

Comment: thanks, other words, is it possible to draw this legend of the pictures? Notice that the legend scale (0,1,2,4,7,10) are evenly distributed in the color bar, but the corresponding scale data is not, but I can only draw scale (0,2,4,6,8,10)

Comment: OK，I create example quick now, and show it in my question , you may see it and help ,thanks

Comment: @tjebo I create example  now, you can see it and question, thanks!

Comment: @tjebo can you help me this?

Comment: I'll see what I can do. Will keep you posted.

Answer (score 0):

For make **Pathway Analysis** Im use this code, and I put a scale color gradrient.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(aes(x=`Enrichment Score (-log10(Pvalue))`,y=Term,
                    size=`Count`,  color=`P value`)) +
         geom_point(alpha=0.9,stroke = 1)+
         scale_color_gradient2(high = '#4101fa', 
                               mid = '#d8006f', 
                               low = '#f20530', 
                               breaks = c(0.002478,0.0012391 ,0.0001511))+
         guides(colour = guide_colourbar(reverse = F))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but that's not what I want, what I want is for the legend scale to be evenly distributed, my scale is c(0,1,2,5,8,10), and the legend show to be evenly distributed, but I failed, I don't know how show that

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear to me what you are really intending to get. One reason for this is that you have not provided a minimal, reproducible example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Anyways, I'm trying to guess what you looking for. You need to set breaks in the call to scale_continuous. Also don't forget to set the limits.

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp, color = cyl))+
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_continuous(breaks = c(0, 1, 3, 7, 10), limits = c(0,10))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-12-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Comparing the legend scale labels in my Figure 1 and Figure 2, you will see that the labels in Figure 2 (right) are evenly spaced, but mine is not. The data in my figure has achieved the goal of having a more obvious gradient between 0 and 3, but the legend is not so pretty and intuitive

Answer (score 0):

After 1.5-years' searching, I finally find the answer:

1. using ggplot2 packege: Set both arguments "**trans="pseudo_log"** " and "**guide = guide_coloursteps(even.steps = T)**" in scale_color_gradientn, you can get the legend you want.

or 2. using plot: plot first without legend, then use **fields::image.plot(zlim=c(0,10),col=rainbow(length(breaks-1)),lab.break=breaks)**